# How to apply the same factor levels to 2 variables containing similar data

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(group1 = factor(c("B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "C", "D", "E", "F", "D", "E", "F", "E", "F", "F")),
                 group2 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "E"))
df$group2 <- as.character(df$group2)
```

And I want both `group1` and `group2` variables to be factors with the same following levels: `"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"`, which originates from another variable (let's call it a vector `vec_fac`):

```
vec_fac <- factor(LETTERS[1:6], levels = 1:6, labels = LETTERS[1:6])
```

So at the end of the day, I want `df$group1`, `df$group2`, and `vec_fac` to all have the same factor levels in the same order. How would I go doing so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) factor(x, levels = levels(vec_fac)))
```

Out:

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   15 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ group1: Factor w/ 6 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 2 3 4 5 6 3 4 5 6 4 ...
 $ group2: Factor w/ 6 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 ..
```

Comment: Which you could squish like `lapply(df, factor, levels(vec_fac))`

Comment: Yeah true. I fall into the habit of using anonymous functions every time :P